# Working sms script for zabbix

Tags: zabbix

Could anyone provide a working script for sending sms from zabbix. I would like to use free service provider. I couldn't find any useful script for this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "content-type: text/html\n\n";
use CGI;
$cgi = new CGI;

$cel = $ARGV[0];
$title = $ARGV[1];
$msgx = $ARGV[2];

&enviasms;

# SOAP (Simple Object Access Protocol)
############################################

sub enviasms{ 

$dispatch = "send";
$account = "myaccount";
$code = "mypassword";
$msg = "$msgx";
$from = "Zabbix";
$to = "$cel";
$id = time();
$user = $id - 1;
$schedule = "";
$callbackOption = "";


use LWP::Simple;
#$result = get("http://system.human.com.br:8080/GatewayIntegration/msgSms.do?dispatch=send&account=$account&code=$cod e&msg=$msg&from=$from&to=$to&id=$id&schedule=$sche dule&callbackOption=$callbackOption");

if(!$result){
use strict;
use warnings;
open (my $fs, '>>', 'log');
print $fs "that is Error\n";
close $fs;
} else{
use strict;
use warnings;
open(my $fs, '>>','log');
print $fs "msg is: ";
print $fs $ARGV[2];
print $fs "::::>phone:";
print $fs $ARGV[0];
print $fs "\n";
close $fs;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check Pagerduty which is not free but is not expensive and brings great value with the android and iPhone apps and it has great integration with Zabbix.

Check this guide:
http://www.pagerduty.com/docs/guides/zabbix-integration-guide-2/

Comment: Thanks. I need a script that works with free service providers.